# Symfony2: security.yml: how can i have two rules for one path

Tags: symfony, access-control

**Symfony2: security.yml-access_control: how  can i have two rules for one path**

I would like to have two role in one path

Example: security.yml

```
access_control:
      - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER}
      - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMINISTRATIVE}
```

I want only ROLE_USER & ROLE_ADMINISTRATIVE who can access.

Answer (score 2):

Just like this path: `{path: ^/path$, role: [ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER]}`